# remove the content of a directory and the directory itself when it become empty

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to write my own rm command using a bash script, my new command called "remove" accept one or several params (file and folders), and it must act like this:

when it found a file : it must check the parent for permission before deleting it

when it found an empty directory, it have to delete it

and the last case, when it found a non empty folder, it must delete all its content after checking permissions for course, and if the parent directory became empty my command must remove it too

My problem is that the third case doesn't work for me

here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
  echo "Executer la commande avec au moins un paramètre"
else 
    for i in $*
    do
        filename=`basename $i`
        #echo "nom fichier : $filename"
        path=`dirname $i`
        #echo "chemin du fichier : $path"
        #Vérification de l'existence du fichier/rep
        if [ -e $path/$filename ]
        then 
          # Si fichier
          if [ -f $path/$filename ]
          then 
            echo "fichier"
            $HOME/droit_parent $path
            valretourne=$?
            if [ $valretourne -eq 20 ] 
            then
              echo "Erreur : `dirname $path` n\'a pas le droitW"              
            else if [ $valretourne -eq 10 ] 
            then
              rm -f $path/$filename
              echo "$path/$filename a été bien supprimé"
            fi
          fi
        fi
        #Si rep 
        if [ -d $path/$filename ]
        then 
          echo "repertoire"
          if [ "$(ls -A $path/$filename)" ]
          then
            echo "non empty directory"
            $HOME/remove $path/$filename/*
            if [ ! "$(ls -A $path/$filename)" ]
            then
              rmdir $path/$filename
            fi
          else
            echo "empty directory"
            rmdir $path/$filename
          fi 
        fi
      else echo "ERREUR : $path/$filename n\'existe pas !"
    fi
  done    
fi
```

Comment: Can you please highlight the section of the code that you think is not working?

Answer (score 0):

In order to find an empty directory I think it would be much easier if you use **find** instead of listing the files/folder in that dir and based on that decide if that dir is empty or not.

You can use find like this:

```
find . -type d -empty
```